# Удалить дефис перед знаком вопроса в url

Tags: .htaccess

Есть ссылка по типу `http://site.com/xxx-10-?bbb=111`
Как мне все подобные ссылки изменить на `http://site.com/xxx-10?bbb=111` с 301 редиректом (удалить "-" перед знаком "?").

Answer (score 0):

```
# включаем модуль mod_rewrite
RewriteEngine On
# если в запросе на конце адреса есть хотя бы один '-',
# то делаем переадресацию с удалением всех этих '-'
RewriteRule ^(.*)\-+$ $1 [R=301,QSA,L]
# другой вариант с указанием домена
#RewriteRule ^(.*)\-+$ https://your.site.com/$1 [R=301,QSA,L]
```